# Java Optional evaluation side Effects

Tags: java, lambda

I had some trouble with the evaluation of Java optionals. Consider the following test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println("GOT STRING: " + first().orElse(second()));
}

private Optional<String> first() {
    System.out.println("Evaluating first");
    return Optional.of("STRING OPTIONAL");
}

private String second() {
    System.out.println("Evaluating second");
    return "SECOND STRING";
}
```

My expectation is that since first() returns a non empty Optional, that second is not evaluated. But in fact the output is:

```
Evaluating first
Evaluating second
GOT STRING: STRING OPTIONAL
```

Trying the function used in orElse in a test:

```
@Test
public void test2() {
    System.out.println("GOT STRING: " + (first() != null ? "FIRST IS NOT NULL" : second()));
}
```

Output:

```
Evaluating first
GOT STRING: FIRST IS NOT NULL
```

Why is the second option evaluated? This seems to be bad?

Comment: If you call `orElse(...)` then the argument will definitely be evaluated. Perhaps you want `orElseGet(...)` which accepts a function that it calls when required.

Comment: Why is your question tagged with "lambda" when you don't have any lambda expressions in your code?

Comment: Because googling always gives lamdas and orElseGet is mostly used with lamda constructs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is the second option evaluated?

Because you're calling the `second()` method, in order to provide the value as an argument to `orElse()`. The value of the argument will be ignored (because you already have a value) but that doesn't mean it doesn't have to be provided.

Basically, this code:

```
first().orElse(second())
```

is equivalent to:

```
Optional<String> tmp1 = first();
Optional<String> tmp2 = second();
Optional<String> result = tmp1.orElse(tmp2);
```

There's nothing optional-specific here - that's how argument evaluation *always* works in Java.

Note that this is a big difference between a *library* construct (`orElse`) and the condition operator *language* construct (`?:`) which will only evaluate either the second *or* third operand, but never both.

As Artur mentioned, if you want to defer the call to `second()`, you need to use `orElseGet`, where the argument you pass isn't the value to use if `first` doesn't have one, but the call to make in order to *get* the value.

Comment: I looked at the implementation for orElse which uses this language construct. So I this should behave equivalent which it does not. But your explanation fits here. This still seems an easy source of errors to me and should be documented. Though you are right with the evaluation. I kinda just forgot that using the function.

Comment: @mrbela: It has to be provided because you have to provide an argument for each parameter. This is all just normal Java behavior - there's nothing magic going on here. It would be pretty odd for the compiler to decide not to evaluate a method argument.

Answer (score 13):

It is evaluated, because you are passing value of `second()` by value, rather than just passing a reference to function itself. You need to do one of following

```
System.out.println("GOT STRING: " + first().orElseGet(() ->second()));
System.out.println("GOT STRING: " + first().orElseGet(this::second));
```

To delay the evaluation till it is really needed.

Answer (score 2):

Because `second()` call is passed as parameter to the method `orElse`, and parameters gets evaluated eagerly in Java.

Should you need to provide a supplier or avoid eager execution, you can use `orElseGet` which expects a `Supplier`

```
optional.orElseGet(()->second()))
```